# Vulnerabilities using model beans in view JSP

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I saw hundreds of examples in Spring and Struts where model beans are used in the view and I would like to know if it could be a vulnerability and what is the best approach to solve it.

A dumb example. We have a model bean:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String pass;
    //getters and setters
}
```

And we have to views (jsp)

1. ADMINVIEW: A view only allowed for admin where we have a form with 2 fields (name and password).
2. USERVIEW: A view for common users where we have a form with 1 field (name)

In the service layer (which should be abstract to the view) we have a method:

```
if(pass.isEmpty)
   createNormalUser();
else 
   createAdminUser();
```

In USERVIEW an intruder could use both fields (modifying the data in the browser for example) due to are opened in both views (USERVIEW and ADMINVIEW) because it is the same bean (User).

Ok it is a dumb example but in a complex webapp a priori you can not guarantee that this behavior with model beans is avoid completely because you can have a complex business logic and hundred of cases where modify a bean could produce an unwanted behavior. Even more, having in mind that service layer should be independent from the view layer.

So it is necessary to control this in the controllers layer (controllers in Spring or actions in struts).

What is the best approach to solve it?

- Using form beans that contains an object of type our bean model with
  getters and setters only for the fields used in the form.
- Validate in each controller that only the fields in the form are
  allowed to come with data
- Other?

Comment: Very interesting question, I have never thought about it. It could be dangerous if it is not controlled. The validation should include not only what data is correct but also what fields have to be completed. I think using form beans is a better way because you only allow data in the fields used in the form.

Comment: It's better to implement a Role based authentication and authorization strategy here as we have two different views for admin and normal user. Spring security will help you for a better management of these kind of scenarios. Spring has security tags which allows you to show and hide the vulnerable parts from unauthorized access.

Comment: It is true, but as you can see in the example even having roles you can't save this vulnerability due to both roles would use the same bean and the method. And depending on the how data of the bean comes, will execute an admin operation or an user operation (if you hack the form in the client and fill the pass field with any data with an user role you can obtain the same behavior of admin role). As I said it is a silly example, but you can find this behavior easily in your bussines logic. And you shouldn't include in the service layer something like {if(role==admin) createAdmin(); ...}